# How to customize the coordinate axes in matlibplot

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, rotation

i have two points `p1=(0.86, 0.5) & p2=(0.86, -0.5)` in which i want to plot them using matlibplot
So i tried the following:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
p1=[0.86, 0.5] 
p2=[0.86, -0.5]
plt.scatter(p1[0], p1[1])
plt.scatter(p2[0], p2[1])
```

I get the following result:

[image]

However, what i want is a rotation between p1 and p2 according to a coordinates system so that it would look like the following:

[image]

So how can i adjust the coordinate system like the picture above?

Comment: Do you want to plot the arrows as well?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This isn't ***precisely*** what you're after, but should give you an idea of how to achieve the desired display. The important bit(s) are where the spine properties and tick marks are set. You can add ticks to the axes to "compress" the view scale to match your example. I've also included an example of one way to display arrows.

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

p1=[0.86, 0.5] 
p2=[0.86, -0.5]

# Create figure and subplot
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1, 1, 1)

# Plot data points
ax.scatter(p1[0], p1[1], color='blue')
ax.scatter(p2[0], p2[1], color='orange')

# Set limits for x and y axes
plt.xlim(-1, 1)
plt.ylim(-1, 1)

# ===== Important bits start here =====

# Set properties of spines
ax.spines['top'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['left'].set_position('zero')
ax.spines['right'].set_color('none')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_position('zero')

# Set axis tick positions
ax.xaxis.set_ticks_position('bottom')
ax.yaxis.set_ticks_position('left')

# Set specific tick locations
ax.set_xticks([-1, -0.5, 0, 0.5, 1])
ax.set_yticks([-1, -0.5, 0.5, 1])

# ===== End Of Important Bits =====

# Draw arrows
ax.arrow(0, 0 , p1[0], p1[1], 
    head_width=0.03, 
    head_length=0.1, 
    lw=1, 
    fc='blue', 
    ec='blue', 
    length_includes_head=True)
    
ax.arrow(0, 0 , p2[0], p2[1], 
    head_width=0.03, 
    head_length=0.1, 
    lw=1, 
    fc='orange', 
    ec='orange', 
    length_includes_head=True)

plt.show()
```

#### Sample Output

[image: Sample output plot]